# The Mystery of the Número Cabalístico

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

I recently ran into an interesting type of number that people from where I was born like to refer to as *números cabalísticos*. They are supposedly "magic" kinds of numbers that possess mystical characteristics that are tightly bound to the celestial or spiritual realms (I could go on and on about it). However, I have only encountered one such number, and it is this one:

> $$142857$$

Notice that if you multiply this number by any of the integers from $2$ to $6$, you will get a different permutation of it, and if you multiply it by the number $7$ (which is a “divine” number), you will get an interesting result:
$$142857\cdot2=285714$$
$$142857\cdot3=428571$$
$$142857\cdot4=571428$$
$$142857\cdot5=714285$$
$$142857\cdot6=857142$$
$$142857\cdot7=999999$$
My questions are: is there a “theory” behind this kind of numbers? Could they be helpful in any way? Are there any others? Is the world ending this year? Thanks, guys!

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_reptend_prime and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theory is in your last line, $142857 \cdot 7 = 999999$, which means that $\frac 17 = 0.\overline{142857}$  Any prime which has full period will do the same.  The next is $\frac {1}{17}=0.\overline{0588235294117647}$ which you can multiply by any number from $2$ through $16$ and get a cyclic shift.

Comment: But now you've taken the *cabalístico* out of it...

Answer (score 1):

Not only 142857 but there are many more similar and even an unproven conjecture is that there are infinitely many. In mathematics these numbers are  known as **cyclic numbers** and there are many references to them in particular see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicNumber.html)